# How to Fix Response.Cookies.Append()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

(Beginner) I am building a small web program that requires a login page in asp.net 2.0 (core).

I followed this tutorial for the login page: https://parallelcodes.com/mvc-login-page-with-sql-database-razor/

After doing some reading i changed:
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Users1", users.UserName));

To:
Response.Cookies.Append(new HttpCookie("Users1", users.UserName));

As add was throwing an error: IResponseCookies Does not contain a definition for add.

I am however now getting: The type namespace name "HttpCookie" could not be found.

Visual Studio's suggestion to fix is to generate a new class, however there is nothing of this sort in the tutorial, and i have no idea what i would put in that class if i created one.

As well as this issue, in the User class, line 32 (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);) the ConfigurationManager will only requiers one argument? I have no idea what to do here.
UserLoginController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MusicAllApplicationv2.Models;

namespace MusicAllApplicationv2.Controllers
{
    public class UserLoginController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UserLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //This the Login method. It passes a object of my Model Class named "User".
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserLogin(User users)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //message will collect the String value from the model method.
                String message = users.LoginProcess(users.AccountID, users.Password);
                //RedirectToAction("actionName/ViewName_ActionResultMethodName", "ControllerName");
                if (message.Equals("1"))
                {
                    //this will add cookies for the username.
                    Response.Cookies.Append(new HttpCookie("Users1", users.UserName));
                    //This is a different Controller for the User Homepage. Redirecting after successful process.
                    return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
                }
                else
                    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = message;
            }
            return View(users);
        }
    }
}
```

User.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

namespace MusicAllApplicationv2.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your User ID.")]
        [Display(Name = "Username : ")]
        public string AccountID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Password.")]
        [Display(Name = "Password : ")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        //This method validates the Login credentials
        public String LoginProcess(String strUsername, String strPassword)
        {
            String message = "";
            //my connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Usertbl where UserId=@Username", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", strUsername);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    Boolean login = (strPassword.Equals(reader["Password"].ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCulture)) ? true : false;
                    if (login)
                    {
                        message = "1";
                        UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString();

                    }
                    else
                        message = "Invalid Credentials";
                }
                else
                    message = "Invalid Credentials";

                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = ex.Message.ToString() + "Error.";

            }
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

UserLogin.cshtml:

```
@model MusicAllApplicationv2.Models.User;
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>UserLogin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>UserLogin</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <table class="table-condensed">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountID)
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountID)
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <br />
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountID)
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" } })
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <br />
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    @ViewBag.ErrorMessage;
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

When run, i want the output to be a login page that is connected to a database. Once the submit button is pushed it should redirect to /Home/Home, as the other pages are under a different controller to the login page.

Current error message:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'MusicAllApplicationv2.Controllers.HomeController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, out ConstructorInfo matchingConstructor, out Nullable`1[] parameterMap)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
Response.Cookies.Append("Users1", users.UserName);
```